# Jsp displaying commas as new line

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a string containing logs (retrieved from log4j file) that I want to display to jsp. 
however jsp is displaying all my comma as a new line.

example string:

> "[createtime, id, totalbooksadded, totalbooksborrowed, totalbooksreturned, reportenddate, reportstartdate]"

In jsp it is being displayed as follows:

```
[createtime
id
totalbooksadded
....
]
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I have tried print the string to console and seems to be printing correctly with commas. Does anyone knows why this is happening? tia

Comment: r u sending this string as a model to jsp page from controller  ? can you please post the jsp code, where you are using this string to create html ?

Comment: yes i am passing the string as a model. here's my jsp code to display <pre><c:out value="${log }"></c:out></pre>

Comment: @user3308224 have you tried printing it using other tags , except `<pre>` as it formats text

Comment: yes and it's same problem commas are rendered as new line